What happens when a ballot measure is incorrectly drafted, but passes anyway?
Many jurisdictions allow for legislation by referendum, where laws can be created or amended by public vote.  In such cases, the text of the proposed legislation is usually printed on the ballot, so that the voters ostensibly know what they are voting on.  I am wondering what happens when that text contains an obvious error.
In a recent local election in Colorado, the ballot included a city-level question to amend certain numbered subsections of the city charter.  However, some of the referenced subsections, as printed on the ballot, do not exist.  The ballot question was nonetheless approved by the voters.
I am curious about the following:

Could a court interpret the question to amend a different section than the (nonexistent) one stated, if they can reasonably guess which section was probably intended?  If not, would it invalidate the entire ballot measure?

Would this be handled differently for a ballot measure than for a similar error in an act of a legislature?  In a legislature, it's somewhat more likely that the legislators would know and understand what amendment they meant to make.  Would a court be willing to assume that voters had that same understanding, or would they recognize that many voters probably didn't really know what they were voting for?



The case I have in mind was Greeley Ballot Question 2J in the November 2023 Coordinated Election in Weld County, Colorado.  The text as printed on the ballot was:

Shall Sections 13-4(a), subsection (a) and 13-4(k), subsection (a), (c) and (e) of the City of Greeley's Charter, related to the Greeley Fire Department, be amended to change the titles of Captain to Battalion Chief, Division Chief to Deputy Chief, Chief to Fire Chief, and add the rank of Assistant Chief?

In the City Charter as of that date, section 13-4(k) is a single sentence about severability that didn't have any subsections (a),(c),(e), and it doesn't have any relevance to the titles "Captain", "Division Chief", etc.
My best guess is that the drafter meant to reference section 13-4(c), which does have subsections (a),(c),(e) that mention "captains" though not the other ranks.  I would also guess that "add the rank of Assistant Chief" only applied to 13-4(a), since it's not clear where you would "add" it in the other sections.
I have not been able to find out how the case was actually resolved.  The latest update of the City Charter doesn't show any changes to Article XIII.

I’m voting to close this question because that is a question for Politics.Se

@Trish: This question is about how laws are interpreted by courts, which I believe is a legal process, not a political one. So it seems to me that it is on topic for Law.SE. It could also be on topic for Politics but that site seems less likely to be knowledgeable about legal interpretation, canons of construction, etc.

These are such significant errors, I wonder if the drafter had been referencing an old version of the City Charter. I also find it kind of weird that renaming Fire Department officer ranks would require a ballot measure.

@Barmar The former is possible, but unlikely. But you'd be surprised what ends up in a city charter - they are almost always unreasonably detailed.

@ohwilleke I'm not questioning these being in the city charter, I'm questioning the need to use a ballot measure to change them. That tends to be needed when the politicians are reluctant to do something, so citizens need to take it into their own hands. Why would FD ranks be so controversial?

I could see it happening when trying to replace titles with gender-neutral ones, if there's a conservative legislature that views it as "woke". But changing Captain to Chief?

@Barmar Generally speaking, a city charter can only be amended by a ballot issue. The city council and mayor can't do it without a public vote. And, while state ballot issues can be hard to organize, it doesn't take terribly many signatures to get a city ballot issue on the ballot, because the petition threshold is a function of how many people vote in municipal elections which is often low. There are all sorts of idiosyncratic reasons that these get organized, and FD ranks are probably tied to the FD pay scale and to what looks good on a resume. City council may not care, firefighters do.

@ohwilleke Yeah, I just realized that myself as I was reflecting on the term "charter" -- it's different from statutes. Just as changing the state constitution requires a ballot measure.

@Barmar: The sections in question define which fire department ranks are eligible for union representation and collective bargaining. So there is some potential controversy. I half suspect that the drafters of the measure deliberately made this obscure.

If the error is truly obvious, the courts should interpret it to reflect the intent of the drafters. This particular instance is one in which that rule of statutory interpretation should probably apply. In the case of a citizen's initiative, the title assigned to the ballot issue and the language in the informational blue book distributed to voters prior to the election explaining the measure, would provide an ample basis to determine the intent of the drafters.
One of the Colorado statutes which governs construction of state statutes is Colorado Revised Statutes § 2-4-203 (which is basically codifying common law rules of statutory interpretation). It states:

(1) If a statute is ambiguous, the court, in determining the intention
of the general assembly, may consider among other matters:
(a) The object sought to be attained;
(b) The circumstances under which the statute was enacted;
(c) The legislative history, if any;
(d) The common law or former statutory provisions, including laws upon
the same or similar subjects;
(e) The consequences of a particular construction;
(f) The administrative construction of the statute;
(g) The legislative declaration or purpose.

Similar rules of construction would be applied to a citizen's initiative amending a city or county ordinance.
Although courts must give effect to a statute's plain and ordinary meaning, the intention of the legislature will prevail over a literal interpretation of the statute that leads to an absurd result. AviComm, Inc. v. Colorado Public Utilities Com'n, 955 P.2d 1023 (Colo. 1998). A statutory construction that would defeat the evident legislative intent will not be followed. See, e.g., In re Marriage of Morton, 369 P.3d 800 (Colo. App. 2016). But courts “will disregard unambiguous statutory language only when the resultant absurdity is so gross as to shock the general moral or common sense.” Department of Transportation v. City of Idaho Springs, 192 P.3d 490, 494 (Colo. App. 2008).

Here in Massachusetts, the "Information for Voters" booklet includes summaries of the ballot measures in plain language, as well as justifications by the proponents and opponents of the measures. I imagine the courts would take this into consideration when determining what the intent of the voters was.

@Barmar Colorado also has a publication like that, sometimes called the "Blue book" (for obvious reasons, it has blue covers), that would be highly influential in determining the intent of the initiative.

And in the example in the question, the intent seems to be clear -- rename  bunch of X to Y. The section numbers are just a minor technicality.

@Barmar It is also worth noting that in the Colorado Revised Statutes there are a small number of instances in which the Revisor of Statutes drops a footnote to note a probably erroneous cross-reference in a statute.

What law gives a ballot measure the authority to create a law there? Most states do not have that.

@Tak Colorado's State Constitution, Article V, Section 1. https://advance.lexis.com/documentpage/?pdmfid=1000516&crid=13825d78-05d3-471c-b147-d2c81b24757c&nodeid=AABAAGAAC&nodepath=%2FROOT%2FAAB%2FAABAAG%2FAABAAGAAC&level=3&haschildren=&populated=false&title=Section+1.+GENERAL+ASSEMBLY+-+INITIATIVE+AND+REFERENDUM&config=0143JAAwODgxYWIyNi1mNGJlLTQwYmItYmE4Ni0yOWY2NzQzMjE3MTAKAFBvZENhdGFsb2ecqetP0coiYGhC4QCG46NJ&pddocfullpath=%2Fshared%2Fdocument%2Fstatutes-legislation%2Furn%3AcontentItem%3A61VF-9YD1-DYDC-J4PC-00008-00&ecomp=6gf5kkk&prid=1e4df128-7e0c-4ca4-8711-152a81dd6c63

Gives local government the right to make law or in the form of a ballot measure?

@Tak The right in the case of local governments is at Article V, Section 1(9) of Colorado's state constitution. "The initiative and referendum powers reserved to the people by this section are hereby further reserved to the registered electors of every city, town, and municipality as to all local, special, and municipal legislation of every character in or for their respective municipalities. . . ."

A survey of where initiatives are available at the state level can be found at https://www.ncsl.org/elections-and-campaigns/initiative-and-referendum-processes and at https://ballotpedia.org/States_with_initiative_or_referendum There are also local initiatives, e.g., in CA https://www.ppic.org/wp-content/uploads/content/pubs/report/R_904TGR.pdf and in parts of Washington State https://mrsc.org/getmedia/1c25ae05-968c-4edd-8039-af0cf958baa7/Closest-Governments-To-The-People.pdf?ext=.pdf Surveyed at https://ballotpedia.org/Laws_governing_local_ballot_measuresignatures%20of%20registered%20voters.

Only four U.S. states (Illinois, Indiana, Arkansas, and Wyoming) have no local government initiative and referendum process at all. https://ballotpedia.org/Laws_governing_local_ballot_measuresignatures%20of%20registered%20voters.

More relevant Colorado law is found at https://ballotpedia.org/Laws_governing_local_ballot_measures_in_Colorado
